# How do I use JQuery in my Javascript?

Tags: jquery

Can someone explain what JQuery is? The internet is telling me i need to "download a copy of JQuery" to get started. What is JQuery exactly? I'm making a table in Javascript and I found something online that's free but uses JQuery and when I just copy the code and put it in mine it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined." I assume it's a library that is part of Javascript, so how would I reference the library and what does it mean when it says download?

Comment: jQuery is indeed a library build with JavaScript. You don't necessarily have to download it, you can also use a CDN (Google it). To make your code working, you need to include jQuery BEFORE your code. Hope that helps.

Comment: You should really have a look at the jQuery website. It can answer the basic questions for you: https://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: This isn't the place for your question. Google will yield more than enough results. Spend some time checking them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery is a JavaScript Library. It simplifies JavaScript programming. It is a lightweight. It takes a lot of common tasks that require many lines of JavaScript code to accomplish, and wraps them into methods that you can call with a single line of code. It also simplifies a lot of the complicated things from JavaScript, like AJAX calls and DOM manipulation.

The jQuery library contains the following features:

- HTML/DOM manipulation
- CSS manipulation
- HTML event methods
- Effects and animations
- AJAX
- Utilities

**Downloading jQuery**

There are two versions of jQuery available for downloading:

- Production version - this is for your live website because it has
  been minified and compressed.
- Development version - this is for testing and development
  (uncompressed and readable code).

The jQuery library is a single JavaScript file, and you reference it with the HTML  tag (notice that the  tag should be inside the  section):

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

**jQuery CDN**

If you don't want to download and host jQuery yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).
Both Google and Microsoft host jQuery.

To use jQuery from Google or Microsoft, use one of the following:

**Google CDN:**

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

**Microsoft CDN:**

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

One big advantage of using the hosted jQuery from Google or Microsoft:

Many users already have downloaded jQuery from Google or Microsoft when visiting another site. As a result, it will be loaded from cache when they visit your site, which leads to faster loading time. Also, most CDN's will make sure that once a user requests a file from it, it will be served from the server closest to them, which also leads to faster loading time.

You can learn more about JQuery from http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Comment: jQuery might be lightweight for today's "standards" (average website is 2.5mb) but it's definitely not lightweight if you compare to other libraries and plugins.

Comment: **Danger** jQuery 3.1.1 is very old and has security issues. I recommend editing the question so, instead of providing the URLs to a specific jQuery version, it explains how to find the most recent jQuery release.

Answer (score -1):

Jquery works very great in combination with javascript.
As I always see this and explain this, that jQuery is a sort of brother from javascript. It actually is a javaScript platform.

However, you need to add a jquery library into your file.
Place the following line inside your `<head></head>` tags and you won't get the error you just had.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is just one of the many jQuery scripts that are around, google a bit for some more.

Answer (score -1):

Jquery is basically just a library for JavaScript, It performs tasks in webpages more effectively than JavaScript and HTML. For example doc traversing into webpages and animation.

To link jquery to JavaScript use the following code obviously with your file name:

```
ar script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```